# Deep Link Tests in Flutter App Automation

Tags: flutter, appium

As a beginner, I've started to write **End to End (E2E) scenarios for a Flutter App using Appium**. Right now **I want to write E2E tests for Deep Link flows**. I'm struggling with find a proper way to do it. Does anyone have insight how to start it?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can trigger adb commands with your scripts and then once the UI is rendered completely on the mobile device, then you can put some assertions on the navigation bar or title or some buttons text as available on the UI.

Below is the adb command to launch profile with Medium android app as below,

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://medium.com/@bipin_k" com.medium.reader
```